# Iteratively subsetting function outputs into a vector

Tags: r

I've seen a few answers on here that are similar, but nothing that actually accomplishes what I'm trying to get done.
I have the following function:

```
reduce_review <- function(pos){

   test_review <- reldata[pos, 1]
   review_words <- as.vector(strsplit(test_review, " ")[[1]])
   review_uncommon <- as.vector(review_words[!review_words %in% common_words])
   review_stems <- wordStem(review_uncommon, language = "porter")
   return(review_stems)

}
```

And I want to output results from this function into the following char matrices (vectors of vectors?) (what I have doesn't work):

```
x_train <- reduce_review(1:500)
y_train <- reldata$stars[1:500]
x_test <- reduce_review(501:1000)
y_test <- reldata$stars[501:1000]
```

so the x_train matrix will contain all results of reduce_review(pos) for pos = 1 to pos = 500, etc.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: `sapply(1:500, reduce_review)`

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!